# How to specify mime-mapping using servlet 3.0 java config?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I am using Servlet 3.0 and looking to convert my existing web.xml file to java config.  Configuring servlets/filters etc seems to be pretty straight away.  I can't figure out how to convert the following mime-mapping.  Can anyone help me out?

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xsd</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced this problem in a Spring Boot application. My solution was to create a class that implements `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` as following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyMimeMapper implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
    mappings.add("xsd", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that this class existed (org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MimeMappings).  While I was hoping for a solution that doesn't depend on Spring Boot, this certainly works for now.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I haven't looked any deeper into this, no.

Comment: @Samuli Kärkkäinen above code is for embeded tomcat, what about external tomcat ?

Answer (score 3):

Just write a `Filter`. e.g. for mime-mapping in web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>mht</extension>
    <mime-type>message/rfc822</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

We can write a Filter instead:

```
@WebFilter("*.mht")
public class Rfc822Filter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resp.setContentType("message/rfc822");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spring MVC, this method worked for me.

In the web-context, add this:

```
public class WebContext implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.mediaType("xsd", MediaType.TEXT_XML);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot set them in Java configuration. You can only do this in the web application's deployment descriptor or your serlvet container's.

The javadoc of [`ServletContext#getMimeType(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29) hints at this

> The MIME type is determined by the configuration of the servlet
>   container, and may be specified in a web application deployment
>   descriptor.

Comment: This is exactly where I wound up.  I am still hoping that there is another way.